# Slow down my own connection

Tags: bandwidth

I want to test a program I have developed on LANs that have a very slow connections.  I have two computers here, I want to run a program on one that will kill the bandwidth on my connection.  Is there a way I can do this from CMD or another 3rd party software?

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094760/network-tools-that-simulate-slow-network-connection/1094779) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest but probably not the best way would be to go to network settings, disable auto-negotiation and set low speed manually and then test away.

Answer (score 0):

If either end is a linux or other common *nix style OS, i'd suggest taking a look at [trickle](http://monkey.org/~marius/pages/?page=trickle). I can't think of any windows tool offhand, but t[here's a thread on the very same topic on MDSN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfp/thread/efc7569d-8d01-4d2d-a80b-bba8a18068cd/) that may be of use